# ruby on rails - open flash charts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying various ways to implement pretty graphs in my app.  I followed http://pullmonkey.com/projects/open_flash_chart2 steps in my app, but instead of creating test_it, I just added to my own controller.  In my routes.rb, I have

```
resources :my_controller_name do
    collection do
      get 'graph_code'
    end
  end
```

also, since I don't think it could find the action my_controller_name/graph_code otherwise (I'm kind of confused as to why most tutorials leave the routes part out? Am I doing something wrong?). (I also used @graph.html_safe in my views for Rails 3)
Anyway when I go to /my_controller_name, I get the error in the flash box:

```
Open Flash Chart

JSON Parse Error [Syntax Error]
Error at character 0, line 1:

0: #<OpenFlashChart::OpenFlashChart:0x000001043c4b78
```

I don't know why this is happening.  I tried creating a new app and following the guide, generating a controller named test_it.  It worked (provided I corrected the routing).  I can't think of how my controller is any different than test_it, except I initially generated it using a rails scaffold (so it has all the MVC parts), whereas I only generated the test_it controller.  (I've also tried using/not using the json gem conflict fix, but it didn't make a difference--https://github.com/klochner/open_flash_chart/commit/00cf531387880af8c49ed5118737f0492b437f75) Thanks for any insight, I'm stumped as to why it's easy to implement on a new app but I can't add it to mine...
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, it seems to work if I use the old lib/base.rb instead of the json gem fix. Ah well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't waste your time with Flash based charting libraries. [Highcharts](http://highcharts.com/) is definitely the way go to. It works in pretty much any browser, including those that don't support Flash. Much better performance on OS X than Flash will ever provide.

Comment: I looked into High charts but the $300+ price tag was too much :/